# Десериализация коллекции объектов JSON

Tags: c#, wpf, json.net

Есть базовый класс и несколько его потомков:

```
class Base {...}
class A : Base {...}
class B : Base {...}
```

И коллекция этих объектов:

```
ObservableCollection<Base> Actions {get;set;}
```

В интерфейсной части для каждого типа объектов определен свой `DataTemplate`, но после выполнения десериализация все объекты коллекции апкастятся до `Base` и не отображают заданный шаблон.

Сериализация производится в  Json с помощью библиотеки от Newtonsoft:

```
public static void Serialize(string path, object savedObject)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(savedObject);

    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    }
}

public static object Deserialize(string path, Type type)
{
   string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);
}
```

Как исправить это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Base {...}
class A : Base {...}
class B : Base {...}

var list = new List<Base>() 
{
   new A(), 
   new B()
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, settings);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Base>>(json, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Помог ответ с английского SO:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6495299/6641468)

Нужно включить типы в сериализацию с помощью [TypeNameHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).
В итоге методы преобразовались следующим образом:

```
public static void JsonSerialize(string path, object savedObject)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(savedObject, settings);

    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        fs.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
    }
}

public static object JsonDeserialize(string path, Type type)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };

    string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type, settings);
}
```